# Cannot scale vertices

Tags: modeling

Currently, I am following some tutorials on the blender. On latest tutorial we were supposed to create a little creature here's the photo of what it looks like in development.

[image]

I am trying to scale those selected vertices to give a more rounded shape. In the tutorial, the instructor successfully does this, however, when I try the scale tool it does not move the vertices.

Why I am failing on this, but the instructor can successfully do it?

Here are the settings I am using:

[image]

Note: I am using Blender 2.77.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE. Can you show a link to the lesson you mention preferably with the time point where this is discussed (or describe a bit where do you want each vertex to move) ? Are you sure you use the same Pivot and other settings same as in tutorial ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears you have set the origin to *Bounding Box Center*.
[image]  Set it to *Median Point*, and this should work.

Comment: The origin in the screenshot is set to Bounding Box.